# Unityに3Dモデルを入れると透明な面ができる

Tags: unity3d

Blenderで作った3DモデルをUnityにいれたら、なぜかこのように面が透明の状態になってしまいます。
どのように対処すれば面が透明の状態にならないでしょうか。[image: gazou]
ちなみに、法線を逆にしても何も起きませんでした...

Comment: 法線を逆にしても何も起きなかったというのは、透明になってしまった面の法線を逆にしても表示されないままだったということだけでなく、透明でない面の法線を逆にしても表示されるままだったということも含んでいますか？　もしそうなら正しく法線を反転できていないかもしれません。